# Installing single receptacle for motor loads and not gfci protect

Tags: gfci

What about installing a single receptacle in the location like garage door openers, sump pumps, disposal, ect...? If hey are dedicated circuits do they still need to be GFCI protected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do outlets in damp locations require GFCI protection?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16317/do-outlets-in-damp-locations-require-gfci-protection)

Comment: different question:

Answer (score 1):

2014 NEC 210.8.A "*All 125-volt, single phase 15- and 20-amp receptacles installed in the locations specified in 210.8.a.1 through 10 shal have GFCI for personal.*" (This means 5 MA trip on detected fault). #2 "*Garages, and also accessory buildings that have a floor located at or below grade level not intended as habitable rooms and limited to storage areas, work areas, and areas of similar use.*"

This means all outlets in the garage require GFCI even ceiling mounted outlets for garage door openers. (My state exempts the dedicated outlet behind a freezer or a large piece of equipment not easily moved. All other outlets except an alarm system require GFCI protection). 
For a Sump pump if you do not want GFCI protection get a 240V pump 120V pumps require GFCI even for a dedicated circuit.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be exceptions in the code for individual 125-volt 15- and 20-ampere branch circuits, where a single receptacle was provided for the attachment of equipment to not require GFCI protection. However, I think all those exceptions have been removed from the code.

If you want to avoid GFCI protection, you'd have to use 240 volt, or "hardwired" equipment.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I remembered that exception. And the exception where if the receptacale was 6'-6" high off the finished floor?